# How to parallel windows pc in same network?

Tags: windows-7, networking, cpu, threads, distributed-computing

I have some windows pc in my local network, each of them have 8 cores cpu.

I have program that takes lot of cpu resource, so I want to parallel it on all of the pc.

Right now I running my program only on my pc, so I create 8 thread because I have 8 cores cpu, and I give each of thread 1/8 of the work , and OS seperate each of thread for each of cores.

I looking for way that pc in my network will be able to share me some of cores so I can give those cores part of work.

In this way , if I have 20 pc that share me 2 cores and I will be able to fire threa to each core, I will be able to give each thread 1/40 of work.

I don't want running it in internet cloud,only on my local network.

Comment: Unless your program supports it, its not possible. What program are we talking about? Also, I removed the tag parallels. Parallels is a VM application for Mac.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link processing power of old computers together?](https://superuser.com/questions/226584/how-to-link-processing-power-of-old-computers-together)